# Choosing format in pack() using struct module in python

Tags: php, python, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to convert a PHP code to python.

**All values are send in network byte order (big endian).**

Basically, the REQUEST in protocol specification is

[image]

and response is

[image]

Corresponding PHP Code ([corresponding DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)) is:

```
$transaction_id = mt_rand(0,65535);
$current_connid = "\x00\x00\x04\x17\x27\x10\x19\x80";
$fp = fsockopen($tracker, $port, $errno, $errstr);
$packet = $current_connid . pack("N", 0) . pack("N", $transaction_id);
fwrite($fp,$packet);
```

I am trying to find the corresponding code ([for doc](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters)) in python:

```
transaction_id = random.randrange(1,65535)
packet = "\x00\x00\x04\x17\x27\x10\x19\x80"
packet = packet + struct.pack("i", 0) + struct.pack("i", transaction_id)
clisocket =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
clisocket.sendto(packet, ("tracker.istole.it", 80))
```

In the response, I should get the same transaction_id I sent in the request which I am not getting. So, my guess is, I am not packing using correct format.

Also, the python documentation is not as clear as that of PHP. The protocol specifies to use Big Endian format & PHP doc clearly states which are the ones for Big-Endian.

Sadly, I could not comprehend which format to use in python. Please help me in choosing the corrent format.

**EDIT:**
Not getting any responses, so I would say more.

```
import struct
import socket
import random

clisocket =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
packet = "\x00\x00\x04\x17\x27\x10\x19\x80"
transaction_id = random.randrange(1,65535)
print transaction_id
packet = packet+struct.pack(">i", 0)
packet = packet+struct.pack(">i", transaction_id)

clisocket.sendto(packet, ("tracker.istole.it", 80))
res = clisocket.recv(16)

print struct.unpack(">i", res[12:16])
```

According to protocol specification, I should be returned same INTEGER.

Comment: Complete doc for the protocol is at http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html#udp-tracker-protocol

Comment: An example that shows on how to retrieve the data using the protocol is at http://linux-junky.blogspot.com/2011/10/get-seeds-peers-completed-info-from.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [php pack function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) format `N` means unsigned 32-bit big-endian integer.
The corresponding [Python `struct.pack`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters) format is `>L`.

The images you posted for the protocol show the `connection_id` should be 64-bit (unsigned) integer: Python struct.pack format `Q`.

So:

```
clisocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
connection_id=0x41727101980
action=0
# transaction_id = random.randrange(1,65535)
transaction_id = 12345    
print(transaction_id)
# 12345

packet=struct.pack(">QLL",connection_id,action,transaction_id)
print(repr(packet))
# "\x00\x00\x04\x17'\x10\x19\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0009"

clisocket.sendto(packet, ("tracker.istole.it", 80))
res = clisocket.recv(16)
action,transaction_id,connection_id=struct.unpack(">LLQ",res)
print(action)
# 0
print(transaction_id)
# 12345 
print(connection_id)
# 2540598739861590271
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote you more than once. THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Comment: Could you please tell me why did you choose Q(unsigned long long) for 64-bit integer and L(unsigned long) for 32-bit integer? I need to know this so that I don't get into trouble while doing this trivial thing.

Comment: 64-bits is 8 bytes. The third column of the [struct.pack format table](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters) entitled "Standard Size" shows which formats correspond to 8 bytes. The 8-byte options are `q`, `Q` and `d`. Since we want unsigned integers, `Q` is the right choice. Similarly, 32-bits is 4-bytes. There are four choices, `i`,`I`,`l`,`L`. I *assumed* the transaction_id should be unsigned, so that narrows the choice to `I` or `L`. They are equivalent. Either one works.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know unsigned long & unsigned int are equivalent. I am wondering if they are same, then why to different formats?

Comment: I think it has to do with `struct`'s [historical connection to C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Integer_types). I quote from there, "In many cases, there are multiple equivalent ways to designate the type".

Answer (score 0):

Endianness is described in [§7.3.2.1 of the library reference](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). Big-endian packing has a prefix of `>`.

Comment: http://sprunge.us/PBLf is my code but I am not being returned the same integer WHILE the PHP code works just fine.